# Starring vs Featuring?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, synonyms

I'm writing a description for a photograph, and I'd like to place the emphasis on the scarf that the person in the picture is wearing. The description would be something along the lines of **"__ the scarf that's been everywhere from New York to London"**. Which word would be more appropriate, **starring** or **featuring**?

Comment: "showcasing" would better fit the context http://www.thefreedictionary.com/showcase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Featuring*** is correct:

> to feature: to include or **show something as a special or important part of something**, or to be included as an important part
>
> *The exhibition features paintings by Picasso.*

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/feature_2))

The verb "to star" is used of famous performers, not things.